# Css className has low specifity than css classes from material-ui v5

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

When using IconButton from @material-ui/core for example in my react app, I applied a className `classes.myCloseButtonstyle`, turns out it has low specificity compared to css classes `.css-1743419-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root` (see screenshot below).

[image: extra material-ui classes]

When I checked the doc here https://next.material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#customized-dialogs
the order is different than what I got in above screenshot. the `classes.myCloseButtonstyle` has higher specificity than this `.css-1uaxfgw-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root` classes (screenshot below is example code from material ui doc)

[image: icon button from official material-ui v5]

what could possibly wrong in my react material ui setup, tho? I need to make the `classes.myCloseButtonstyle` win the specificity. No, I mean, I need to make the order of `.css-1uaxfgw-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root` and
`classes.myCloseButtonstyle` be reversed.

styles order from material-ui doc:

1. `classes.myCloseButtonstyle`

2.`.css-1uaxfgw-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root`

syles order in my app:

1. `.css-1uaxfgw-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root`
2. `classes.myCloseButtonstyle`

I need to change the order to be:

1. `classes.myCloseButtonstyle`
2. `.css-1uaxfgw-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root`

Comment: you can use `!important` to impose your style.

Comment: yeah, but I need different solution. I don't wanna use `!important` in this case.

Comment: See this https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-style-changes/#style-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/24109#issuecomment-751125891

I solved it by follow this version 5 material ui CSS order injection issue

Answer (score 0):

To increase the priority of a CSS `class` you need to increase the specificity of a class.

> check this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to increase specificity

Mean while to solve your issue try `button.myCloseButtonstyle` in your css file to increase the class priority.

Comment: I am sorry, I updated my question. what I meant by increasing specificity is I need to reverse the element style `.makeStyle-myCloseButtonStyle-23` and .`css-1743419-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root` (see pic. 1) position, so that `.makeStyle-myCloseButtonStyle-23` comes before `.css-1743419-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root`

Answer (score 0):

You can increase specificity by specifying path:

```
div > div > buttonm.makeStyles-myCloseButtonStyle-23
```

or simply repeating class:

```
div > div > buttonm.makeStyles-myCloseButtonStyle-23.makeStyles-myCloseButtonStyle-23
```

[As w3org says:](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity)

> Note: Repeated occurrences of the same simple selector are allowed and
> do increase specificity.

Comment: I am sorry, I updated my question. what I meant  by increasing specificity is I need to reverse the element style  `.makeStyle-myCloseButtonStyle-23` and `.css-1743419-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root` (see pic. 1) position, so that  `.makeStyle-myCloseButtonStyle-23` comes before `.css-1743419-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root`

Comment: @KhairaniF I do not think that if you reverse the order, then it will add specificity. You can edit order of classes manually and see whether it is will give you desired result. However, if you add specificity like in my reply you can increase specificity and your style might be win and desired color will be applied

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I just needed to add StyledEngineProvider and Specify injectFirst like this:

```
<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
 </StyledEngineProvider>
```

You can read in the documentation here: https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-style-changes/#style-library
Credit to @Paolo Forgia for pointing out the documentation.